# TweepError: Failed to parse JSON payload:

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to scrape twitter data but I am getting this error. How do it fix it ? I have referred couple of queries over internet but cannot relate the program.

code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import sys
import time

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

ckey = 'abc'
csecret = 'abc'
atoken = 'abc'
asecret = 'abc'

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret, 'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
if (not api):
    print ("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    print " Scraping data now" # Enter latitude & longitude and then radius in Kms  q='hello'geocode="19.9974533,73.7898023,1000km"
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='olympics',since='2016-08-18',until='2016-08-19',lang='en',count=1000)
    results=[]
    for item in cursor.items(10000): # Remove the limit to 1000

        results.append(item)

def toDataFrame(tweets):
    # COnvert to data frame
    DataSet = pd.DataFrame()

    DataSet['tweetID'] = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetText'] = [tweet.text.encode('utf-8') for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetRetweetCt'] = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetFavoriteCt'] = [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetSource'] = [tweet.source for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetCreated'] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userID'] = [tweet.user.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userScreen'] = [tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userName'] = [tweet.user.name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userCreateDt'] = [tweet.user.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userDesc'] = [tweet.user.description for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFollowerCt'] = [tweet.user.followers_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFriendsCt'] = [tweet.user.friends_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userLocation'] = [tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userTimezone'] = [tweet.user.time_zone for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Coordinates'] = [tweet.coordinates for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['GeoEnabled'] = [tweet.user.geo_enabled for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Language'] = [tweet.user.lang for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_place= []
    #users_retweeted = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.place:
            tweets_place.append(tweet.place.full_name)
        else:
            tweets_place.append('null')
    DataSet['TweetPlace'] = [i for i in tweets_place]
    #DataSet['UserWhoRetweeted'] = [i for i in users_retweeted]

    return DataSet

print "started writing the output"       
DataSet = toDataFrame(results)
DataSet.to_csv('olympics_18_8.csv',index=False)
print "Download Completed"
```

I am seeking help for changing th code workable without any errors. If tweepy is the problem here then can I use tweethyon if so how to do i change the code to avoid the error and have a dump downloaded.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scrape_lat_lon.py", line 30, in <module>
    for item in cursor.items(10000): # Remove the limit to 1000
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 197, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 117, in next
    model = ModelParser().parse(self.method(create=True), data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/parsers.py", line 95, in parse
    json = JSONParser.parse(self, method, payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/parsers.py", line 54, in parse
    raise TweepError('Failed to parse JSON payload: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to parse JSON payload: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 467050 (char 467049)
```

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Can you add the error log on your post?

Comment: @KostasPelelis Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error: "*Failed to parse JSON payload: Unterminated string starting at...*". Problem is at the python's `json`, after installing `simplejson` the problem is resolved, no more error.

No changes in my code, just installed the simplejson.

I did this: `pip install simplejson`