# TweepError: Failed to parse JSON payload: Expecting value or ']': line 1 column 689339 (char 689338)

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get the tweets from some users timeline and save it to a csv file, but when I run my code I get this error TweepError: Failed to parse JSON payload: Expecting value or ']': line 1 column 689339 (char 689338)
for some users it works, I don't know the reason for this, but how can I solve this error and why this error showed up ?

this is my code

```
def get_all_tweets(screen_name):

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

alltweets = []
#tweets_mention = []

new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

#save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

#save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

#keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
    print ("getting tweets before %s" % (oldest))

    #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=5000,max_id=oldest)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    print ("...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets)))

#transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text] for tweet in alltweets]

#write the csv  
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
    writer.writerows(outtweets)`
```

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41157563/5078746

Comment: already checked it and it does nothing

Comment: Add .encode("utf-8") to tweet.text in the bottom line `tweet.text.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: the code works fine but the data in the file is unreadable it has an encoding problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a problem with Arabic tweets right ?
in the line where you construct your 2D array, add `encode("utf-8")` to `tweet.text`  the line will be:

```
#transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]
```

Then verify your Code/Console encoding. I tried the script and it works perfectly on Atom.